# JavaScript - document.write not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to print an h3 that has an id of question, but it won't work.

```js
function questions() {
  var question = document.getElementById("question");
  document.write(question);
}

questions();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Edu Game 1</h1>
    <h3>What is<h3 id="question">1+1?</h3></h3>
    <input type = "text" id="ansBox" />
  </div>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the result is fine until it reaches the JavaScript. How can I fix this? I know document.write isn't the best thing to use to print stuff, but I am just testing something.

Comment: Woah. You have the same name as me. Are we related?

Comment: What are you expecting `document.getElementById("question")` to return and what are you hoping to display? `document.write` is rarely the right way to go.

Comment: I am hoping to print out 1+1, the text of the h3.

Comment: Change the last line in `questions()` to `document.write(question).innerHTML;` to reference the text with the HTML element.

Comment: `document.write()` is pretty much never the right way to go. If you use it after the plage-load has completed, you will end up with an empty page. for logging use the `console`, if you want to add something to the DOM, use `node.textContent` or `node.innerHTML` or `parent.appendChild(node)`, ... and some more

Comment: Oh and you can't nest headings

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById("question")` returns a DOM object (as you saw) and you want to access the HTML within it, so use the `innerHTML` property to get it with `document.getElementById("question").innerHTML`. So technically there's nothing wrong with `document.write`; it's doing its job. You're just not selecting the content of the element.

```js
function questions() {
  var question = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML;
  document.write(question);
}

questions();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Edu Game 1</h1>
    <h3>What is<h3 id="question">1+1?</h3></h3>
    <input type = "text" id="ansBox" />
  </div>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

question is an object of type HTMLHeadingElement. You are writing the string representation of that object, which is [object HTMLHeadingElement].

You are either interested in the raw HTML used to generate that element (question.outerHTML) or its contents (question.innerHTML).

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for dom content to load by placing your script in here:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  // code...
});
```

Set `question` with `innerHTML`

`var question = document.getElementById("question").innerHTML;`

Also, dont nest the  tags, use a span instead:

`<h3>What is<span id="question">1+1?</span></h3>`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to write an HTMLheading object into the page. 
Use the `.outerHTML` property for this to work.

```js
function questions() {
  var question = document.getElementById("question").outerHTML;
  document.write(question);
}

questions();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.header {
  padding-top: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h1>Edu Game 1</h1>
    <h3>What is<h3 id="question">1+1?</h3></h3>
    <input type = "text" id="ansBox" />
  </div>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```